# Socket.io page refresh disconnects from the room

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, socket.io

I've been reading answers about this problem for some time now but none of the solutions seem to work for my setup.

I have a nodeJS server in conjunction with express. I use Socket.io to send notifications to individual users. (frontend is Angular)

When a user logs in, he joins a room named after his email address (unique).

```
  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('join', function(user) {
      //list of connected users
      connected_users.push({socket_id: socket.id, email: user.email});
      socket.join(user.email);
    });
    ...
```

The `join` event is broadcasted from angular when a user logs in.

This way I can send notifications like so simply by using email addresses:

```
io.sockets.in(to).emit('notification', {
  message: msg,
  source: from,
  destination: to,
  event: data
});
```

When a user manually logs out I register the following event listener:

```
socket.on('leave', function(user) {
  //remove the user from the list
  var index = findUserConnected(socket.id);
  if(index != null) {
    connected_users.splice(index, 1);
  }
  socket.leave(user.email);
});
```

And finally there's the `disconnect` handler for whenever a user logs out or refreshes the page:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
  //if the user refreshes the page, he is still in the connected users list
  var email = findEmailUserConnected(socket.id);
  if(email != null) {
    //we make him join back his room
    socket.join(email);
  }
});
```

Technically this works. On page refresh, the user joins back his room.

The problem is only on page refresh, notifications sent using `io.sockets.in(email).emit('notification', {});` are not received even though the user is in his room.

Apparently a page refresh calls `socket.disconnect()` which generates a new socket_id. I'm not sure if there's a way to reassign a socket_id to a room or something similar.

Comment: A page reload destroys all page resources including a webSocket/socket.io connection.  Loading the page again creates a new connection.  You will probably need to use a cookie to create some sort of lasting session id so you can identify a previous user and restore their state on the server.

Comment: @jfriend00 what does it mean to "restore their state on the server"? I already have socket.join when the page is refreshed, the user is identified...etc.

Comment: Upon the `connection` event, you need to be able to recognize a socket that you previously had configured into a room and set its state back the way you want (put it back in a room, update the `socket.id` that belongs to this user, etc...  Usually, one would use information obtained from a cookie to associate this new incoming connection with a particular user that you have previously seen before.

Comment: I understand but how and where do I "update the socket.id"? Can I set the socketid of a room? I do have a record of the unique email address and the corresponding socketid. I already rejoined the room. Where do I put that socketid?

Comment: Update what socket.id?  There's no socket.id of a room.  A room has a name and it has a list of sockets that are in it.  That's all a room is.

Comment: Ah, I didsn't know a room had a list of sockets. I only name a room with an email address and do a join(email). I'll try to find how to list the sockets of a room then.

Comment: i just want to clear up things. this means that when a page was refresh or a user goes to a different page. the established connection from `socket.emit('join', {}); - socket.join()` will be lost right? and the only solution is to run the `socket.emit('join', {}); - socket.join()` on every pages right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok first of all receiving a 'disconnect' event on server means that connection on that socket is going to terminate. So, there is no use for making that same socket join back in a room as you are doing right now.

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    var email = findEmailUserConnected(socket.id);
    if(email != null) {
        socket.join(email); // this would never work because this socket connection is not going to exist anymore.
    }
});
```

My suggestion would be to make sure that the user always joins back into the room(email) every time a new connection is made. It can be easily done by adding sending the join event on every new connection.
In your client side code do

```
var socket = io();
socket.on('connect', function() {   //  'connect' event is received on client on every connection start.
    socket.emit('join', user);  //  where 'user' is your object containing email.
})
```

This way it ensures that whenever a new connection is established the join event is sent to server and the 'socket.on('join',...)' listener in your server will add the new socket to the room. Hope this helps :)